# Finding how many intersections two parabolas have within a certain domain

Tags: quadratics

I need to find out if $y=x^2-\sqrt{200}x+50$ and $y=a(x-\sqrt8)^2$ how for what values of $a$ they will have only one point of intersection within the domain $[\sqrt8,\infty)$?

Comment: By intercepts, do you mean intersections?

Comment: Yes, I mean intersections.

Comment: Set them equal to each other and solve the resulting quadratic equation. There’s really nothing more to it.